# Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'string' in anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently using Typescript in my react project and I am trying to call an API in my anchor tag but I get the following error:

```
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

My code is as follows:

```
GetSupplierCertificate(certificate: string) {
    return this.get(ApiUrls.supplierCertficate + '?id=' + certificate);
}
    getCertificate = (certificate: string) => {
    return this.state.service.GetSupplierCertificate(certificate);
}
                <td>{EmpoweringSupplier ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</td>
                <td><a href={this.getCertificate(CertificateId)}>View Certificate</a> </td>
```

my interface:

```
    interface AnchorHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    download?: any;
    href?: string;
    hrefLang?: string;
    media?: string;
    ping?: string;
    rel?: string;
    target?: string;
    type?: string;
    referrerPolicy?: HTMLAttributeReferrerPolicy;
}
```

my BaseApi service:

```
    export class BaseApiService {
  get<T>(url: string): Promise<ResultWithValue<T>> {
    return axios
      .get(`${baseApiUrl}${url}`)
      .then((response: any) => {
        return {
          isSuccess: true,
          value: response.data as T,
          errorMessage: "",
        };
      })
      .catch((ex: any) => {
        return {
          isSuccess: false,
          value: {} as T,
          errorMessage: ex.message,
        };
      });
  }
```

and my promise function:

```
    export interface Result {
  isSuccess: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
}

export interface ResultWithValue<T> extends Result {
  value: T;
}

export const toResult = <T>(value: T): ResultWithValue<T> => ({
  isSuccess: true,
  errorMessage: '',
  value: value
})

export const toPromiseResult = <T>(value: T): Promise<ResultWithValue<T>> =>
  Promise.resolve(toResult(value));
```

The error occurs in my `<td><a>`, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You haven't shown us enough for us to be able to help you specifically, but clearly `this.get` returns a promise, not a string, so `GetSupplierCertificate` returns a promise, not a string, and so `getCertificate` returns a promise, not a string. Moreover, it's a `Promise<void>`, not a `Promise<string>`, so we can't even show you how to use the promise's fulfillment value. Basically: A) You need to wait for the promise to settle before you use it (typically in a `useEffect` callback or `componentDidMount`), and B) You need to update `this.get` so its fulfillment value is a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the question with more content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `await` in the href tag